# Visual Studio thinks my controls are missing, but they're not. "The name xx does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction

When working with an ASP.NET application in Visual Studio 2008, my errors window often contains a list of errors such as;

The name 'txtUsername' does not exists in the current context.

When I double click on the error, it will go to the source, show the control underlined in red, then realise it's mistake and remove those errors. It's a real pain because if you have a genuine error, you have go and hunt for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried building the site?

> Build -> Build Web Site

Comment: Ah. Looks promissing. I was doing Shift-Ctrl-B. Just tried this and it worked once. Will try again.

Comment: Nope - doesn't seem to fix it. I have a genuine compile error, but 40 other "The Name..." errors.